# How to do reverse DNS lookup in Java?

Tags: java, dns

I can see that there is an entry for the reverse lookup of the a given IP address using nslookup.

```
nslookup 54.193.201.195
Server:     172.16.0.23
Address:    172.16.0.23#53

Non-authoritative answer:
195.201.193.54.in-addr.arpa name = ec2-54-193-201-195.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com.
```

However, when I try to do the same in Java using the approach listed in several stack overflow answers I keep getting the same input IP as the canonical hostname.

```
//Always prints the IP address I input
addr = InetAddress.getByName("54.193.201.195");
log.debug("Host Name: {}", addr.getCanonicalHostName());
```

How can I get back the hostname entry back instead of the same IP that I started with?

Comment: That works for me. Are you saying you get back `54.193.201.195`?

Comment: Yes, I am getting 54.193.201.195 back

Comment: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/accessing-the-dusty-corners-dns-java lists a way (using PTR record look up)

Comment: It works for me too. You could try setting google dns as java default and check again by using:
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.nameservers", "8.8.8.8");
System.setProperty("sun.net.spi.nameservice.provider.1", "dns,sun");